# @EnableAspectJAutoProxy deactivate my bean definition

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

I setting up a new Spring App(not spring boot) in IDEA,and manual download aspectjweaver,
writing the following code to practice aop.

A root configuration class is:

```
@Configuration
/*@EnableAspectJAutoProxy*/
@ComponentScan
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx=new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(Main.class);
        ctx.refresh();
        Performance performance=ctx.getBean(WoodStock.class);
        //System.out.println(ctx.getBean(Audience.class));
        performance.performance();
     }
}
```

and the project layout is:

```
+com.dawn.www
  -Main.java
  +aspect
    -Audience.java
  +music
    -Performance.java
    -WoodStock.java
```

I want the `Audience` being the aspect of `WoodStock`(seeing it in spring in action)

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class Audience {
    @Before("execution(* com.dawn.www.music.Performance.performance(..))")
    public void silenceCellPhones(){
        System.out.println("-----------Silencing cell phones");
    }
}
```

`Performance` is a simple interface which implements by `WoodStock`

```
public interface Performance {
    void performance();
}

@Component
public class WoodStock implements Performance{
    @Override
    public void performance() {
        System.out.println("WoodStock Performance start,singer singing+++++");
    }
}
```

`@ComponentScan` should find the`WoodStock`bean which is defined in application context,however when I run it:

```
   No qualifying bean of type 'com.dawn.www.music.WoodStock' available
```

but when I comment out `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`, WoodStock can be fetched from 
application context?that's why?

Comment: I test the same code in spring boot ,which use @Autowired ApplicationContext,it succeed satisfying my intend,that's more weird!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When you are using @EnableAspecjAutoProxy, spring will automatically
   create proxy for all the matching beans(i.e. WoodStock via Audience aspect).
2. Now, Since you haven't used 'proxyTargetClass=true' on
   @EnableAspectJAutoProxy, it will fall back on JDK proxy instead of
   CGLIB.
3. JDK proxy is interface based, hence your proxy is of type
   'Performance'.
4. Thats the reason you are getting 'No qualifying bean of type
   'com.dawn.www.music.WoodStock' available' when you try to find bean
   using WoodStock type
5. Now, after commenting out @EnableAspectJAutoProxy, WoodStock becomes a
   simple bean and is accessible via ctx.getBean(..)
6. with 'proxyTargetClass=true', CGLIB proxy is enabled and it creates
   proxy of type WoodStock

Suggestions

> Use 'proxyTargetClass=true' with ctx.getBean(WoodStock.class)

or

> Use 'proxyTargetClass=false' with ctx.getBean(Performance.class)

Comment: nice comment Arjun !I've figured out it already.but I test AOP on spring boot without `EnableAspectAutoProxy`,and get bean `Woodstock` directly from `ApplicationContext`,does spring boot autoconfigures to the CGLib mode?

Comment: Ohh, you are using SpringBoot, then YES. SpringBoot does configure it as CGLIB proxy. Please refer AopAutoConfiguration.java class from spring-boot-autoconfigure-*.jar

Answer (score 0):

`Performance performance=ctx.getBean(Performance.class);`
Spring Aop only support Interface-level proxy when not using CGLIB,so don't use class,use interface.